# How to show shapefiles with Bing map in asp.net

Tags: shapefile, bing-maps, asp.net

I want to display my shapefile data on bing map using ASP.NET.

Its an web application.

I don't want to use any third party tool for shapefile conversion.

Answer (score 1):

GeoServer has native support for Shape Files. You can add them individually or by folder. It's not recommended for production environments, but it is quite good.

You don't say anything about what mapping technologies you propose to use. OpenLayers will allow you to show overlays over a Bing map.

Answer (score 0):

If the ShapeFiles are not large you can parse these into another format and overlay them on Bing Maps as raw shapes. I have a good code sample on how to do this as part of a larger project I've been working on of spatial tools for Bing Maps here: https://mapstoolbox.codeplex.com/

If your shapefiles are large it is best to import them into a spatial database like SQL 2008, 2012, or Azure. And then create a dynamic tile layer which turns the data into an image on the fly. Here are some useful blog posts if going taking this approach:

http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2009/11/26/dynamic-tile-layers-in-the-bing-maps-silverlight-control/

Comment: Here are some additional resources: http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2013/07/31/how-to-create-a-spatial-web-service-that-connects-a-database-to-bing-maps-using-ef5/
http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2013/08/05/advance-spatial-queries-using-entity-framework-5/